# How can I avoid OutOfMemoryErrors when using Commons FileUpload's DiskFileItem to upload large files?

Tags: java, servlets, out-of-memory, heap-memory, apache-commons-fileupload

I am getting OutOfMemoryErrors when uploading large (>300MB) files to
a servlet utilizing Commons FileUpload 1.2.1. It seems odd, because
the entire point of using DiskFileItem is to prevent the (possibly
large) file from residing in memory. I am using the default size
threshold of 10KB, so that's all that should ever be loaded into the
heap, right? Here is the partial stack trace:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
       at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
       at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:177)
       at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.get(DiskFileItem.java:334)
       at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile.getBytes(CommonsMultipartFile.java:114)
```

Why is this happening? Is there some configuration I'm missing? Any tips/tricks to avoid this situation **besides increasing my heap size**?

I really shouldn't have to increase my heap, because in theory the most that should be loaded into memory from this operation is a little over 10KB. Plus, my heap max (-Xmx) is already set for 1GB which should be plenty.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When dealing with file uploads, especially big ones, you should process those files as streams which you slurp into a medium-size in-memory buffer and copy directly into your output file. The wrong way to do it is to inhale the whole thing into memory before writing it out.

[The doc on commons-upload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html) mentions, just below the middle, how to "Process a file upload". If you remember to copy from the inputstream to the outputstream in reasonably sized chunks (say, 1 MB), you should have no problem.

Comment: At first I didn't think your comment applied to my situation, because I wasn't processing the file directly; I was wrapping the FileItem instances in Spring's MultipartFile class. I looked closer at the code, however, and it was calling MultipartFile's getBytes() which returns the entire contents of the file. I unwrapped my FileItem from MultipartFile, then processed the files as recommended in the documentation. This solved my problem.

Comment: @RobertCampbell, i have come across same problem and it is not getting resolved. Could you please provide the solution you tried

Answer (score 1):

While Carl Smotricz's answer is probably better in the general case, the exception you get is a JVM bug that is reported here:

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6478546